# Positivity conjecture for Somos sequences

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrences, cluster-algebras

Let $\{s_n\}$ be the Somos-$4$ sequence, which is defined by $$s_{n+4}s_n=\alpha s_{n+3}s_{n+1}+\beta s_n^2.$$ It is known that $s_n$ is a Laurent polynomial: $s_n\in\mathbb{Z}[s_1^{\pm1}, \ldots, s_4^{\pm1},\alpha, \beta].$ From the article [Speyer, D. E. Perfect matchings and the octahedron recurrence](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10801-006-0039-y) we know that $\{s_n\}$ (and Somos-$5$ as well) satisfy the "positivity conjecture": all coefficients in this Laurent polynomial are positive.

Is the "positivity conjecture" known for Somos-$6$-$7$ sequences?

Comment: I think this is proved in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403417.